# Are sci-kit learn classifiers iterable objects?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to save a large classifier; unfortunately, I keep getting a memory error due to its size.  I have tried pickle and joblib.  Does anyone know if [streaming pickle](https://code.google.com/p/streaming-pickle/) will work?  Are sci-kits model objects iterable?

Comment: What happened when you tried to iterate over one?

Comment: If it is a `RandomForestClassifier` you can save the individual trees (check the `estimators_` field) into separate files